# get and set value in python

Tags: python, global

I want to have few global variables in my python code.
Then set their values with set function and want to get their values through get function.

For example:

```
a = None #global variable1

b= None #global variable2

def set(var, value):
  var = value

def get(var):
  return var

set(a, '1')
get(b, '2')
```

I want to have a generic get and set function which will do this for any global variable. How can I do this in python ? The code written here gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to pass the variable names as strings, you can do this using the `globals()` function. But even though you can, I don't think it's a good idea.

First, here's how you could do it:

```
def get_var(var_name):
    return globals()[var_name]

def set_var(var_name, value):
    globals()[var_name] = value
```

I'm not using the name `set` since that's a builtin type, which you probably don't want to shadow with something else.

You'd call it like:

```
set_var("foo", 1)

bar = get_var("foo")

print(foo, bar) # prints 1 1
```

So it works, but there's really no need for those functions. You can assign or fetch global variables using normal syntax instead. Just use `foo = 1` instead of `set_var("foo", 1)` (if you're doing it in a function, put `global foo` first). Getting a global variable is as simple as naming it (like I do in `print(foo)`).

If you don't know the variable name ahead of time, you should probably be putting the name and value into a dictionary, rather than making them global variables. Variable names are for the programmer to use. They're not data!

Comment: This is not working. I got value of a and b as declared global.  I did like this `a = ''
b = ''

def get_var(var_name):
    return globals()[var_name]

def set_var(var_name, value):
    globals()[var_name] = value

set_var(a, '1')
get_var(a)
print a

set_var(b ,'2')
get_var(b)
print b`

Comment: When you call `get_var` or `set_var`, you need to put quotes around the name. If you don't you'll be passing those variable's previous values to the function, not their names as strings.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much but why its not a good idea? @Blckknght

Comment: Variable names are for the programmer to use. If the programmer knows what variable he's assigning to, he doesn't need to call a function to assign to it, he just uses regular assignment syntax. If the variable name can't be known in advance, it's not going to be any use to the programmer. If you just want to associate two pieces of data (a name and a value), use a dictionary and map the name (as a key) to the value. That's actually what Python does behind the scenes with global variables, but it's better to use your own dict for your own data rather than reusing the `globals()` dict.

Answer (score 0):

Python is "call by value" not "call by reference". Meaning when you call "set(a, '1')", you are passing the value of "a" to the function "set". The variable "var" in "set" is a local variable to the function itself and will not effect your global variable "a". You need to give your setter and getter methods access to your global variables. You can do this by making them all part of a class object.

Comment: I'd be very careful using the terms "call by value" and "call by reference" when describing how Python works. It doesn't work the same as either of those call styles in languages that support both (like C++). A description I like is "pass by pointer value". Each argument is a pointer to an object, and that pointer is passed by value (copied) when it is passed to the function. So you can't rebind the pointer and have it reflected in the calling code (since you'll only be modifying your copy), but you can mutate the referenced object in place and those changes will be seen outside the function.